# Typing U prints 6, I prints 7 and so on. Can be fixed with AutoHotKey script?

Tags: autohotkey

My keyboard is misbehaving.

When I press <kbd>U</kbd> it types 6. <kbd>I</kbd> types out 7 and so on until <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys, which work fine.
Interestingly enough numbered keys <kbd>6</kbd> and so on work perfectly fine.
What would be the AHK script to patch my misbehaving keyboard to type properly again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd make sure it's the keyboard. If you can borrow one from somebody and confirm it doesn't have this problem, then I'd probably replace the one you have (or potentially clean it). Also make sure nobody installed a faulty hardware keylogger or other nefarious device in between your keyboard and computer that might be messing up your keystrokes.

If you try to script it, you'll have to keep editing your script as the keyboard develops more eccentricities, until finally it stops working altogether. There's also no guarantee the offsets or replacements are reliable or repeatable.

Comment: Other keyboard work fine. I can't replace it because it's a builtin laptop keyboard(I forgot to mention...). The keyboard is clean. I ran some scans beforehand and nothing infected came up.

Comment: Check to see if the "fn" or other special function key is jammed, if not jam on that key a couple of times to see if will unjam.

Comment: @shinjijai
If I hold the fn key it does type the proper letter. Kind of reversed in my case isn't it?

Comment: yah that sounds messed up, can you try to reboot? and if your laptop has this, boot up to the diag and run the keyboard diag and see what's happening there.

Comment: **SOLUTION:** I think someone else gave this answer before me, but they removed their post :(

But anyways the solution:

Had NumPad enabled. Needed no disable it since I have no "true" NumPad on my laptop's keyboard(laptop is small so keys U,I,O, and so on are used as NumPad keys if enabled)